# Autenticação Webservice Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, web-service, autenticação, delphi-xe5

Usei `WSDL importer` para importar o `WSDL` do `webservice`, mas estou tendo dificuldades na autenticação da consulta, ao importar informei usuário e senha, para o `WSDL importer`, e também tentei informa o usuário e senha no método `GetWebservice`, para o `HTTRIO`, algo como:

```
RIO.HTTPWebNode.UserName := 'user'
RIO.HTTPWebNode.Password := 'pass'
```

Mas sempre me retorna o **erro:**

> exception class ERemotableException with message 'Erro Autenticação
>   WS'.

A `url` é esta https://spcpreproducao.cdl-sc.org.br/spc-web/ConsultaSpcscService?wsdl,
como nunca trabalhei com `webservices` estou tendo um pouco de dificuldades em setar ou utilizar a autenticação.

Grato.

Comment: Tenho um manual, no qual é feito um exemplo no SOAP UI, no mesmo consegui fazer uma chamada, mas a propriedade : Authentication Type, está preenchida com o valor: Preemptive, provavelmente seria somente setar o tipo de autenticação para este modo no delphi, mas não encontro propriedade no HTTRIO